# Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, and MaptoApiVersion

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am having trouble with the following use of `MapToApiVersion`. From http://localhost:5000/swagger, the 1.0 Docs and 2.0 Docs render the swagger ui properly and the corresponding swagger.json file is available. The 3.0 Docs fail to render and the swagger.json file does not appear to be generated.

The actual service is up and running properly for all 3 versions. If I hit it from postman, I get the response I expect.

This is running the 1.1.1-rc1 of Mvc.Versioning and 1.0.0 of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. Full .csproj below

Full code at https://github.com/senften/AspNetCoreVersionedWebApi/tree/maptoapiversion

I don't see any errors or have any exceptions when I run this in debug in Visual Studio Code. Have I screwed up the startup or declaration or have I simply run into a bug either in the shim or swashbuckle?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using VersionedWebApi.Model;

namespace VersionedWebApi.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// GoodByeController, just saying Goodbye!
    /// </summary>
    [ApiVersion("1.0", Deprecated = true)]
    [ApiVersion("3.0")]
    [Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class GoodByeController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default Get call returning Goodbye world!
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(GoodByeWorldModel), 200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 404)]
        public GoodByeWorldModel Get()
        {
            return new GoodByeWorldModel();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default Get call returning Goodbye world!
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("3.0")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(VersionedWebApi.Model.v3.GoodByeWorldModel), 200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 404)]
        public VersionedWebApi.Model.v3.GoodByeWorldModel GetV3()
        {
            return new VersionedWebApi.Model.v3.GoodByeWorldModel();
        }
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SwashbuckleAspNetVersioningShim;

namespace VersionedWebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup()
        {
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvcCore().AddVersionedApiExplorer();

            // Adds versioning capabilities, defaulting to version 1.0 calls if available
            services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });

            // Add generated documentation
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
                SwaggerVersioner.ConfigureSwaggerVersions(c, provider);
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ApplicationPartManager partManager, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            // Generate swagger.json
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Let's enable SwaggerUI
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                SwaggerVersioner.ConfigureSwaggerVersions(c, provider);
            });

            app.UseMvc();
            // This is new for v1.1 and is a behavioral breaking change from previous (including 1.1-beta)
            // See the release notes: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/releases/tag/v1.1-rc1
            app.UseApiVersioning();
        }
    }
}
```

csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <Company />
    <Description>A .NET Core Web API project demonstrating versioning a Web API and generating interactive documentation with Swagger.</Description>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/senften/AspNetCoreVersionedWebApi</RepositoryUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="1.1.0-rc1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SwashbuckleAspNetVersioningShim" Version="1.0.0-beta4"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0"/>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make couple of changes to your code.

1) Change below code to

```
    [ApiVersion("3.0"), Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class HelloController : Controller
    { }


    [ApiVersion("3.0"), Route("api/v{api-version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class HelloController : Controller
    { }
```

2) Add MapToApiVersion 1.0 to avoid conflict

```
[HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GoodByeWorldModel), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 404)]
public GoodByeWorldModel Get()
{
    return new GoodByeWorldModel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you've run in to is a behaviour of the shim library.

When the Swagger document is generated the `ApiVersion`s specified on the controller get applied to all of the methods within it where they're not explicitly set to something else.
In this instance because there is no `MapToApiVersion` attribute on the `Get()` method it gets added to both the V1 and V3 Swagger documents because that's what's specified on the controller. This then causes an overload error whilst generating the Swagger doc.

The good news is it's a simple fix, just add `[HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("1.0")]` to your `Get()` method so it looks like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Default Get call returning Goodbye world!
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(GoodByeWorldModel), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), 404)]
public GoodByeWorldModel Get()
{
    return new GoodByeWorldModel();
}
```

The `Get()` method will then only get added to the V1 doc and the rest of your code can stay exactly as it is.

There's a bit more detail about this behaviour on the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/rh072005/SwashbuckleAspNetVersioningShim#note-about-maptoapiversion) for the Shim